# PHP script doesn't work when using wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I installed wamp server on my windows 7 machine. It shows that all the services are running. It has Apache running, PHP running and also MySQL. I have the latest Chrome browser installed.

I am trying to run the following code on the website, but I just get the basic html page without the PHP script.

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Php Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h3>Php tutorials</h3>
    <hr>

    <a href="?page=home">Home</a>
    <a href="?page=tutorial">Tutorials</a>
    <a href="?page=about">About</a>
    <a href="?page=contact">Contact</a>
    <hr>

    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    echo "testing";
    print_r($_REQUEST);

    ?>

</body>
```

I looked around and they suggested me to install PHP, Apache and MySQL. I have all three running with phpMyAdmin using wamp server. What am I missing?

I fixed the issues with testing being regarded as not a string and added error reporting, but I still don't see testing being displayed on the webpage.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` You have an unset constant (`testing`) and no `$_REQUEST` array to see, Enclose `testin` in quotes and get rid of the `print_r()` statement.

Comment: You can also add errors through the wamp menu.  wamp->PHP->PHP Settings->Display Errors

Comment: `testing` is being treated as a constant. *Right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: What @JayBlanchard said to use, would have triggered an Undefined constant testing notice.

Comment: *<title>Php Tutorial</title>* <- That's in your title tag? And your first php line is this: `echo testing;` well that's not the best start into a tutorial!

Comment: as per your edit: Is your file extension in fact `.php` and how are you accessing it? as `http://localhost/file.php` or as `file:///file.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29830084/1) - What @JayBlanchard said to use in regards to using error reporting, would have triggered an Undefined constant testing notice.

Therefore, you need to wrap the word "testing" in quotes:

```
echo "testing";
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Consult the manual on strings:

- https://php.net/language.types.string

and on constants:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

If you want to use a constant all you need to do is define it:

```
define('testing', 'this part gets printed, not the name of the constant');
```

The accepted convention is to use upper case words for the name of the constant, so rather than 'testing' it would be 'TESTING'.

```
define('TESTING', 'this part gets printed, not the name of the constant');
```

Then you can use the constant:

```
echo TESTING; // no quotes, echos 'this part gets printed, not the name of the constant'
```

---

**Edit:**

as per your edit: Is your file extension in fact `.php` and how are you accessing it? as `http://localhost/file.php` or as `file:///file.php`?

> OP: it looks like file:///C:/xy

- It should be `http://localhost/file.php`

Comment: Hello Fred, the issue still remains even after I added the changes you asked for. Please see the updated text.

Comment: @SUB How does your browser url looks like: `file:///C:/xy` OR `localhost/xy` ?

Comment: @SUB I posted a comment under your question about that ^

Comment: it looks like file:///C:/xy

Comment: @SUB 100pt. for me! Maybe you want to access the file from the server and not the file via the filesystem :)

Comment: thank you fred. that makes some sense. How do I find which folder is the root for my wamp server?

Comment: @SUB it should be located under the default installation folder and placing that file inside it. Usually c:\wamp\www\ which is what I have from the default install of my Wamp. Their documentation also mentions it.  http://www.wampserver.com/en/ *"The “www” directory will be automatically created (usually c:\wamp\www)"*

Comment: thank you so much fred. I will use wamp folder to save my websites.

Answer (score 1):

That should read:

```
echo "testing";
```

you are missing the quotes.